# Assuming value in Libreoffice: Can I calculate a formula using values that were calculated if input cell had a certain value?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

My Libreoffice Sheet shows a table of table soccer results.

```
Day        Team A       |        Team B       | Winner
1 | Player A | Player B | Player C | Player D |   A
2 | ...
```

From this table I calculate another table for a specific player, in which it says how often this player played with or against every other Person, how often he has won or lost with or against him or her.

```
Mark  | Played with | Played against | Victory with | Defeat against
Julia |      7      |       3        |       3      |       0
Andre |      8      |       0        |       8      |       0
Jim   |      4      |       18       |       2      |       12
... hundreds of different players
```

This is a table with Data for Mark. It has a row for each player. It reads like this: Mark has played 7 times with Julia and 3 times against her. Together they have won only 3 times and Mark has never lost against Julia. Andre is a strong player. Mark never plays against him and whenever he played with him, they have won. And so on.

From this table I can calculate the favorite opponents and favorite teammates. But if I want to do that for each player, I need the same table that I have for `Mark` for all other players. That would basically be a *Copy & Paste Action* for hundreds of players.

Let's say `Mark` is in Cell `A1`. Can I get the results for this table **assuming** `A1` would be `Julia` without actually writing "*Julia*" into `A1` and without copying the table with its calculations?

Comment: How about using data validity to make a drop-down box in A1 of all players. Then select `Julia` and the formulas will update for that player. Or, if you need all of the results for every player but don't want to copy them by hand, you could write a macro.

Comment: @JimK Yes, I need all of the results. So then I may try to write a macro. Never did that before and it's good to know what I can use a macro for. I'd still appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction using a macro.

Comment: For Basic, check out [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php). For Python, see [this introduction](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) and [Transfer from Basic to Python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python), using the [APSO extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python).